# Dynamically building a sql statement with Node error

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

I am trying to dynamically build a mysql statement but I keep getting incorrect syntax.

```
const tableName = user_data;
const insertSet = {'id': 1, 'dependents': ['sarah', 'john']}
conn.query('insert into ?? set ?', [tableName, insertSet], (err,rows) => {
  if (err) reject(err);
  resolve(rows);
}
```

When I try this I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax

In the error message, I saw that the sql it tried to run is

```sql
insert into user_data set id = 1, dependents='sarah','john';
```

It took away the array from `dependents` and this caused the syntax error.

It should be

```sql
insert into user_data set id = 1, dependents=[ 'sarah','john' ];
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have arrays, just can't set `dependents` to an array of strings like that.

Comment: What is the datatype of `dependents`?

Comment: A typical insert query uses `values` rather than `set`. Are you using some sort of ORM that rewrites queries to SQL or that's meant to be SQL in the first place?

Comment: Never mind, I always forget that MySQL allows that variation as well.

Comment: The array I am testing on is boolean actually. something like [true, false]. for the example, I just simplified it to string

Comment: It does the same thing when i have dependents = [true, false]

Comment: So is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: @siri can you share the schema of the table? what data type does the column have?